# Multiple Types of Objects in Java containers

Tags: java, containers

I am learning about generics in Java, and was wondering if this would be considered poor coding.

If I declare an `ArrayList<Object>` I know that I can put any type of object into this list, as all objects descend from Object. I also know that when I call `ArrayList.remove(index)` the object that gets taken out of the array is of type Object, and that I need to typecast it to the type of object that I want to use.

Now suppose I have object of `Dog`, `Cat`, and `Car`. Would it be bad to put all three objects into the array, considering they are not similar classes?

Comment: Yes. this can lead to runtime classcast exceptions. generics is to ensure compile time checks so your code is type safe

Comment: In the end, it depends on the context. There's nothing at all to say that it is wrong *per se* to store `Dog`s, `Cat`s and `Car`s in the same list, and there certainly are cases where it is the right thing to do; it depends only on why you're doing it. If you could provide a bit more context on why you want to do this, that would help in giving a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us revise the definition of a `Collection`, as [found in the Java *Introduction to Collections* tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html):

> A collection — sometimes called a container — is simply an object that groups multiple elements into a single unit. Collections are used to store, retrieve, manipulate, and communicate **aggregate data**. Typically, they represent data items that form a **natural group** [...].

Look at the bold words. That should give you your answer.

If you put objects in `ArrayList` which do not belong to same implementations, you are definitely inviting trouble in situations when you want to retrieve objects from the list and typecast them to appropriate types. So you should **AVOID** doing that.

Consider you store objects of `Dog` and `Car` in `ArrayList`.
Then for each object stored, you want to call some method, say `barkLoudly()`. Now,this method will work fine with the `Dog` object. But when this is called on `Car`, **boooom**....An `Exception` will arise.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is "usually, but not always."  There's not a lot of hard and fast rules in coding;  if you look hard enough you can always find an exception.  But if you pull objects out of a collection that you then have to cast to the correct type, that's usually a design error.

Try to make code so that the objects you work with already have the correct type for what you want to do.  If you don't need to cast, then Object can be fine.  If you do need to cast, you should probably rethink your design.

Answer (score 1):

The design will be really bad, to avoid all such kind of issues, Generics were introduced.
But the same you can achive using below, provided you have same type of objects.

> Cat and Dog extends Animal
>
> Car and Bike extends Vehicle

**But do not mix the the above two statements.**

**Animal class:**

```
public abstract class Animal {
    protected String name;
}
```

**Dog class:**

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

**Cat class:**

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat Cat = new Cat("C");
        Dog Dog = new Dog("D");
        ArrayList<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        list.add(Cat);
        list.add(Dog);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You shouldn't do this**

Lets look at it this way, if an we call a generic `Object` just a "thing" and you create a(n) (`Array`) List of just "things" then how useful is that to you? To store those three things that have seemingly nothing in common in one list doesn't make sense. Containers were added so that programmers could store groups of *similar* things.

If we take a look at it from more of a programming point of view as opposed to a real world point of view it raises more problems. Your code might try to perform an action that only `Car` can do, the compiler doesn't like that your `Dog` class just tried to `turnOnEngine()`, and throws an error that you didn't expect.

So in short, it is bad practice to add unrelated items to a collection.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to use the `List` for.

You should declare the generic type value of the `List` to be the most restrictive that suits your needs, and that way you get the strongest check from the compiler to eliminate the errors at compile time.

There might be cases when you really just want to store any type of objects in a `List` in which case you would use `List<Object>`. Again, depends on what you want to use the `List` and the elements for.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of generics is to have the compiler doing all the type checking for us. So that we don't need to worry about casting or have to remember what types are really in the list. So using generics also helps ***documenting*** your code by making the contained type more explicit.

You could:

- *not use generics* and enforce your own type checking (by safe downcasting with instanceof)
- use generics *with separate lists* for each type
- use generics *with an abstraction for related class*, for example: `List<Animal>`